# Audio Recorder recording silent

Tags: sound

I just installed Audio Recorder on an Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to record something from my system's output. Unfortunately it does not record anything. It shows up perfectly, as if it would record, but I just get "silent" files. I tried all possibilities with the audio source, both on Audio Recorder and on my system: "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo (Audio Output)", "System's default device" - on the app and "Analog Stereo Duplex" (the default) and "Analog Stereo Output" on my system, but the result is the same: silent audio files.

What should I do? Thank you,

Comment: silly question (I ask because it happened to me once) but did you look at the input level at the right of the input source (system setting)

Comment: Another silly question perhaps, but shouldn't you record from your input devices rather than your output devices?

Comment: @Jos sharp! didn't notice that one.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm Sorry, there is no input source here, but output source. Usually you record from an input source, as Jos mentioned, but Audio Recorder is designed specially for recording from some of your PC output (I'd use it to record some internet radio streams). You can record also from microphone, or both (mic and some output) as I understand it.

Comment: Btw, this Audio Recorder works in Ubuntu 13.04, where I installed it a few days later.

Answer (score 1):

First, Search for **PulseAudio** in your machine

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJVLF.png]

If not installed, you can find it in Ubuntu Software Center (PulseAudio Volume Control)

Next, open the built-in sound recorder and press record.

Then, open PulseAudio, go to **recording** tab. You should see this picture

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSYE4.png]

If the Record Stream *from* option is "Built-in Audio", then change it to "Monitor of Built-in Audio".
You should now see your recorder working.